# (Java) Thread safety using Object wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was looking for a way to make one thread wait/sleep until another thread signalled that something was ready. The waiting thread should wake up, process the data that was made available, then go back to sleep until the other thread signalled again.

The simplest method I could find was `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`, which behaved like a semaphore initialised to value 0. However, without the `synchronized` statements around `notify/wait`, Java always threw `IllegalMonitorStateException` when the thread was not the monitor owner. So I simply put them around the code like shown below.

**THREAD 1: running infinite loop**

```java
public class Main {
    private Handler handler; // only one instance (singleton pattern)

    public void listen() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (handler) { 
                    handler.wait();
                    int value = handler.getSize();
                    // do something
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THREAD 2: Some other class calls removeItem**

```java
public class Handler {

    // SINGLETON PATTERN - ONLY ONE INSTANCE

    private ArrayList<Integer> sharedList;

    private Handler() {
        sharedList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(Integer i) {
        synchronized (sharedList) {
            // add to list
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int i) {
        synchronized (sharedList) {
            // remove item

            // notify that something is removed
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify(); // this == handler
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        synchronized (sharedList) {
            return sharedList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work perfectly fine but not sure if there is a hidden bug. 
My question is: Is this safe? Does `wait` release the instance lock for `handler/this` so `notify` can acquire the lock?

Comment: 1. Yes, `wait` explicitly releases the lock so other threads can use the class ("explicitly" means it's in the docs somewhere, I just didn't look it up).

Comment: There's kind of a hidden bug in that `Main` uses the lock externally, but all of `Handler`'s methods encapsulate the lock.  That's weird.  I would be consistent in my encapsulation and make `listen()` a method in `Handler`.

Comment: And I disagree with Software Engineer.  Synchronizing on `this` is quite common.  There's reasons to not do it, but there's probably equal reasons to do it.  For example, when you take the lock of `Handler` in `Main`, there's valid reasons why sometimes you need to be able to do that. You should however document when you synchronize on `this` because it's now basically part of your object's public API.

Comment: When you wait for something, you need to check for that something. This check must happen within the same `synchronized` block. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) says, the check and wait should even happen in a loop, before acting on the condition, still while holding the lock as otherwise, there is no guaranty that the condition still holds. Since it’s hard to believe that your `// do something` does something useful with only having the `size`, it’s very likely that whatever happens there, is broken.

Comment: Re, "\[wait() and notify()...\] behaved like a semaphore." **NO!** A Semaphore _remembers_ that it was signalled. `wait()` and `notify()` have no memory. If some thread A calls `o.notify()` at a moment when no other thread is waiting, then `notify` does _nothing at all_. If some other thread B subsequently calls `o.wait()` then it will wait until the _next_ time (if any) that some other thread calls `o.notify()`.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized blocks are safe. The statement `synchronized(obj)` acquires the lock of the argument `obj`, so you can call `wait` and `notify` on it. They both require that the current thread holds the lock on the object.

You have to be careful about the double-locking you have in `removeItem` where you lock two objects. If you ever need this, you have to make sure that you always lock them in the same order, otherwise, you may create a deadlock.

Comment: I didn't notice the OP was locking both `this` and `sharedList`.  That's a good catch.  As long as `this` is always held when `sharedList` is accessed (read or written) there's no need to lock also `sharedList`.  The `this` lock will suffice.